# How to get accessToken directly from google-auth-library

Tags: google-oauth, google-cloud-run, google-auth-library

I have a cloud run in my GCP project, and normally I've used google-auth-library like this

```
  const auth = new GoogleAuth();
  const client = await auth.getIdTokenClient(url);

  await client.request(...)
```

And it works fine. But now I need only the accessToken to send request from other HTTP client. So I've tried:

```
  const auth = new GoogleAuth();
  const client = await auth.getIdTokenClient(url);

  console.log(await client.getAccessToken());
```

But this gave me na error

```
Error: No refresh token or refresh handler callback is set
```

so I don't just get accessToken without implementig refreshing?

Comment: Your code is finding credentials using ADC. What credentials did you setup? Where is the code running? Edit your question to show more details. Also, include the imports and package versions.